# How can I prove the operator definition of $H$ and $p$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, hamiltonian

I was reading quantum mechanics and i can't understand the operator definition of Hamiltonian and momentum? 
From where they are using them without proof? 
Is it in principles?
If somebody know it i'll be thankful for proofing that.

Comment: What are the axioms that your book assumes? In other words, where would the proof start?

Answer (score 3):

The operator definitions of $H$ and $p$ stem from classical mechanics, or more precisely, Hamilton-Jacobi-Theory. Starting from de Broglie's hypothesis, a particle can be described as a wave
$$\Psi = e^{\frac{i}{\hbar} S},$$
where $S$ is the action function, which is thought of as a generating function with the following property:
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial q} = p.$$
Now calculate $\partial \Psi / \partial q$:
$$\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial q} = \frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{\partial S}{\partial q} \Psi = \frac{i}{\hbar} p \Psi.$$
Rearranging the above equation yields
$$p\Psi = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial q} \Psi,$$
which corresponds to the operator definition of quantum mechanics.

From here on it is quite easy to derive the Hamiltonian. Since the kinetic energy of a particle is $p^2 / (2m)$, the Hamiltonian is
$$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(q) = \frac{1}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial q^2} + V(q).$$